# How can I use adk Library

Tags: android

I'm new to android and trying to learn hardware interaction in android

1. have to root to install driver of hardware.
2. can I use adk library for custom hardware development.

As shown [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html), 
if using accessory mode, then **accessory must power the bus.**
But as specified [here](http://source.android.com/tech/accessories/guide/custom.html), 
**accessory can be anything as keyboard too.**
So i got confused: how can a keyboard power the bus?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You misinterpreted those sites.
When you want to connect something like a keyboard, your android device must be in host mode. It will provide power to the keyboard.

The android device will only attempt to draw power from the other device if the other usb device acts as host.

> In USB host mode, the Android-powered device acts as the host.
>   Examples of devices include digital cameras, keyboards, mice, and game
>   controllers.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer can u please suggest some sites to start with adk as i want to start developing app which can recognise the camera

Comment: I think [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/adk2.html) is a good guide for starters. I hope you find it useful.